# what to do if this error "storage size of `temp_q_trig1' isn't known" occurs in ST programming

Tags: compiler-errors, plc, gcc-warning, st, br-automation-studio

I have been programming on ST for some time but I am not familiar with data types and its errors especially the compiler based ones

What is that error and what is the cost of the error and how to solve this error in B&R AUTOMATION STUDIO 4.10?

Comment: It could be a problem in declaring the types. Could you add part of your program so we can check?